Testing Active Admin Page with RSpec
In my Rails application, ruby 2.6.5, rails 6.1. I use Active admin and I created this page. How can I create some tests for this using rspec?
I have already created tests for the model and the controller.
ActiveAdmin.register BxBlockTermsAndConditions::TermsAndCondition, as:  "TermsAndConditions" do

  permit_params :description, :account_id

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :account_id
    column :description
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :account_id, label: "Conta"
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :id
      row :account_id
      row :description
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
    end
  end
end

Someone can help me?
How to test the page

It's a normal request spec. For example, if you want to test the index action
RSpec.describe Admin::TermsAndConditionsController, type: :request do
  let(:admin_user) { create(:admin_user) }

  before { sign_in admin_user }

  describe "GET" do
    it 'index returns http success' do
      get main_app.admin_terms_and_conditions_path
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
end

Check your rails/routes to be sure about the path
